# Can "finish" be used in the following way?

Tags: word-usage

Example dialogue:

> Speaker A: "I like the work. It's just that---"
>
> Speaker B: *The pay is too low?* I wanted to finish.

Is that usage correct? Or I have to use another word? Or writing something like *finish **the sentence***?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you please identify which words were said by speaker A and which by speaker B?

Comment: I take it you're contemplating finishing the statement made by another person with whom you're having a conversation, but *restraining yourself from interrupting*.  Is that right?

Comment: ... or did  speaker A start the sentence,  speaker B interrupted and speaker A said "I wanted to finish"

Comment: @JavaLatte I edited the question.

Comment: Why would anybody say "The pay is too low? I wanted to finish"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming

> I wanted to finish

Is said by the same person who said

> I like the work. It's just that---

If that is the case, a more natural line would be the "command" form:

> Let me finish!

Which is a request to the other person to allow you to finish your sentence.

Comment: And in informal British English, it would usually be preceded by something  "Hang on a minute..."

Comment: Sorry, these are two speakers. And the second one is finishing the other's sentence.

Comment: You should have waited for clarification of the question ;-)

Comment: This exchange doesn't make sense with the clarification. Why would speaker B say that?